# How to integrate sql db to an existing db osm?

Tags: sql, database, openstreetmap

I set up my own tile server thanks to osm, postgresql, postgis and mapnik.
With nominatim-3 I can do research on the map of Cameroon that I imported.
I received a new database in .sql format containing information to add to my map.
I want to integrate this new database into my existing database so that I can see my map updated.
how to do it ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the content details of your SQL database.

Comment: @scai how can I send  my SQL database to you ? It's too long to post it here

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, that's not what I meant. Your database has to contain at least all the information Nominatim will need. You have to take a look at an existing Nominatim database to find out which scheme and which tables are needed. Then transform your database into this format. Alternatively export your database to a valid OSM XML format and let Nominatim import it for you. Both solutions aren't really straightforward, though.

Comment: Sorry to ask that but it's my first time to develop SIG application. Where can I find an existing Nominatim database ? Is there any tutorial to make the transformation from sql format to nominatim format? If so where can you find these tutorials?

Comment: The transformation depends on *your* exact database scheme which you haven't told us by now. Every database can have a different scheme, different tables with different rows, depending on the use case. The easiest way for finding a Nominatim database is by [installing Nominatim](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/). StackOverflow is not really suited for these kind of questions.